# How many groups can keycloak handle

Tags: authentication, oauth, authorization, keycloak, redhat

How many groups can keycloak handle. Iam creating an application where groups are created according to the organisation's register and there will be multiple groups under that organisation as companies. How many organisation and sub company group can keycloak handle

What if the case a million of groups

I need to know how much keycloak is reliable